# How to add Image to ImageView dynamically?

Tags: android, android-imageview

I am doing a project in which user can add upto 10 images. When user clicks on "Add new image" button an imageview will be created. I have implemented this in a horizontal scrolling imageview, so that user can scroll horizontally for viewing the images. On clicking on an image, user will be able to add image from camera or gallery. Now the issue is always the image is getting setted on the last imageview even though I clicked on other imageviews. I don't know how to set the image in the selected imageview.

I have referred this (http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/03/insert-imageview-dynamically-using-java.html) link for dynamically creating imageview in horizontal scrollview.

Following is my code:

On clicking on the button imageviews will be added dynamically:

```
btn_upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                addImageView(image_layout);
        }
```

});

This is the addImageView function:

```
  private void addImageView(LinearLayout layout) {

    imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.gallery);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(220, 220);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setId(temp);
    layout.addView(imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            iv_id = v.getId();

            showDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_ID);  
        }
    });
}
```

This is the code for selecting image from camera or gallery :

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    if (id == CONTEXT_MENU_ID) {
        return iconContextMenu.createMenu();
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();

            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {
                SelectedImage = extras.getParcelable("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                SelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                imageData = baos.toByteArray();
                image = Base64.encodeBytes(imageData);
                filename = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis();

                imageView.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage); //setting the image

            } else {
                image = "";
            }

            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());

            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();

            break;
    }
}

private void doCrop() {

    final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setType("image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    int size = list.size();

    if (size == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot find image cropping application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);

        intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        if (size == 1) {

            Intent i = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);

        } else {
            for (ResolveInfo res : list) {

                final CropOption co = new CropOption();
                co.title = getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);
                co.appIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                cropOptions.add(co);
            }

            CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
            builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                            startActivityForResult(
                                    cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                    CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                        }
                    });

            builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                        getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                        mImageCaptureUri = null;
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us the **CODE**. so we can help you.

Comment: `I have implemented this in a horizontal scrolling imageview,`. Do you put up to ten images in one ImageView? No i think as you are creating new ImageViews. So please clarify.

Comment: `private void addImageView(LinearLayout layout, String image) {`. What does String image contain?

Comment: `imageView = new ImageView(this);`. Change that to `ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);`. You use a 'global' imageView in `imageView.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage);` and now you fill it with the last one. You should set the global imageView when the user clicks one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a class variable `ImageView`
like

```
ImageView addImage;
```

change your click method like this

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        iv_id = v.getId();

        addImage = (ImageView)v  // added code 

        showDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_ID);  
    }
});
```

and finally in `onActivityResult` replace this line

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage); //setting the image
```

with

```
addImage.setImageBitmap(SelectedImage); //setting the image
```

hope you will understand the actul problem.